# Don't understand why this C code is giving different outputs for similar inputs

Tags: c

New to C programming here. I have this piece of code:

```
typedef struct
{
    int length;
    char structure[3][10];
}STRUCTURE;

STRUCTURE STRUCTURE_LENGTH_MAP[3] = 
{
    {
        10,
        {
            "llnnllnnnn",
            "llnlllnnnn"
        }
    },
    {
        9,
        {
            "llnnlnnnn",
            "llnllnnnn",
            "llnnllnnn"
        }
    },
    {
        8,
        {
            "llnlnnnn", 
            "llnnnnnn", 
            "llnnllnn"
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    printf("%d\n", STRUCTURE_LENGTH_MAP[0].length);
    printf("%s\n", STRUCTURE_LENGTH_MAP[0].structure[0]);


    return 0;
}
```

If I print the output for first entry in `STRUCTURE_LENGTH_MAP` (for length = 10), I get this wrong result. It's printing all the entries in structure list:

```
10
llnnllnnnnllnlllnnnn
```

But if I print the output for second or third entry (for length = 9 or 8) I get the expected result like this:

```
9
llnnlnnnn
```

Expected result:

```
10
llnnllnnnn
```

Comment: You can only store 9-char strings in a ‘char array[10]’ - the 10th char is 0-termination.

Comment: What's with the SHOUTING?  Avoid shouting in code.

Comment: @MortenJensen Damn it. changing the size from 10 to 11 fixed it. But this has to be the case of "Why tho" to C from me. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: C allows you to initialize an array of 10 characters with 10 bytes, none of which are null bytes — so the array is not containing a string (because a string ends with a null byte).  If you'd printed `structure_length_map[0].structure[1]` (or `[2])`, you'd see shorter outputs — probably (printing byte arrays that aren't null-terminated with `%s` leads to undefined behaviour). C++ does not allow that — it assumes you must have wanted a string, and therefore you must provide enough space for the null terminator.

Comment: Nit: `ALLCAPS` names are generally reserved for system use and macros. It's not an error, more an accepted convention.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are just stacked characters, to mark the end of the string `\0` is used as an extra character.

So to store `"hello"` string, it is not only 5 character but actually 6, 5 for every character and 1 for the null character, aka `'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' '\0'`

You are missing this extra character in the string that is 10 characters long.

> The Null character is used to end character strings in the C coding language.

> '\0' marks the end of the string

in your struct, make the length 11 not 10 to have enough size to store this character.

This also explains why other entries work, they do store `\0` but for the first entry that has 10 characters, there is no place for the `\0` thus the function `sprintf` just breaks and don't know when the string ends

Comment: @EldinurtheKolibri Look at https://www.javatpoint.com/null-character-in-c

Comment: @EldinurtheKolibri yes, exactly this phrase "C coding language" is used at the given URL.

Comment: It's good to emphasize the difference between an *array of 5 characters* and a *C-string that contains 5 characters*. You have it correct, but making sure to emphasize the difference -- that a string in C also includes space for and the nul-terminating character helps cement the difference. As an example all functions in `string.h` require a C-string. That's why you don't have to provide the length in `strlen(str)`. The nul-terminating character tells `strlen()` when to stop counting (and why the absence of one results in *Undefined Behavior*) Also note plain `0` and ASCII `'\0'` are equal.